# Replacing some values with an hyperlink with jQuery

Tags: html

I have the following html code:

```
<table id="MatrixTable">
    <tr>
        <td id="321"> 0 </td>
    </tr>
</table
```

A. How can I replace the '0' text with an hyperlink when mouseover with jQuery like the following:

```
<table id="MatrixTable">
    <tr>
        <td id="321"> 
            <a class="modal-dialog-link" href="Edit?matrixID=321" updatefunction="UpdateMatrix">
                0
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

$("table#MatrixTable td").mouseover(function () {
    // doing something here...
});
```

B. How can I come back to the original '0' when mouseleave with jQuery like the following:

```
$("table#MatrixTable td").mouseleave(function () {
    // doing something here...
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want them to be links only with mouseover. It doesn't make sense in my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to bind an event handler to the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, and you can use [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) and [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to wrap the contents in an `a` element:

```
​$("#321").hover(function() {
    $(this).contents().wrap("<a>"); 
}, function() {
    $(this).find("a").contents().unwrap();   
});​​​​​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SaKuN/). Inspect the DOM to see the changes as you hover over the element.

This seems like a very strange way to use a link though... why can't the link always be in the DOM?

Comment: I need this because I have a table with about 2500 elements in it. If I define each link I have an html of 360Kb. If I only set a value and define the link with jQuery I have an html of 130Kb. Does it make sence?

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$("table#MatrixTable #321").hover(function () {
     $(this).html('<a class="modal-dialog-link" href="Edit?matrixID=321"'+   
           'updatefunction="UpdateMatrix">0</a>');
},function(){
     $(this).text('0');
});
```